# MessageBox.Show appearing over an RDC

Tags: c#, messagebox, remote-desktop

So I posted a question a while ago about a MessageBox popping up over a remote desktop connection, and the answer I got(below) was working fine until I decided to play around with the program.

```
private void Alarm()
{
    MessageBox.Show(this,
                "Your text",
                "Settings Needed",
                MessageBoxButtons.YesNo,
                MessageBoxIcon.Question
                MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1,  // specify "Yes" as the default
                (MessageBoxOptions)0x40000);
}
```

Now I am trying to call this method from an OnChanged event, and I get an error

> "Additional information: Cross-thread operation not valid: Control
>   'Form1' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created
>   on."

My knowledge is a bit limited on threading, but do I have to create a new thread just for this?

Or is there another way for me to have a MessageBox appear over a Remote Desktop Connection?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Do you execute `Alarm` on a background thread?

Comment: Can you post your code which is calling `Alarm`? I'm pretty sure this doesn't have to do with RDP as much as it has to do with threading.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see what this has to do with Remote Desktop. You are using `Form1` on a background thread. UI controls must be used on the UI thread.

Use one of the various ways to call into the UI thread and show your message box from there.